# Why is Enumerable.OfType<TResult>(IEnumerable) doesn't work as expected with ValueTuple?

Tags: .net, linq, generics, type-parameter, valuetuple

## Behavior

So I have a collection of Tuple that looks like this:

```
public List<(ElementRowViewModel Parent, ElementBase Element)> ResultCollection { get; private set; } = new List<(ElementRowViewModel Parent, ElementBase Element)>();
```

When I try to do the following

```
private async Task RegisterAndCommitElements<TElement>() where TElement : ElementBase
{
    var specificElements = this.ResultCollection.OfType<(ElementRowViewModel parent, TElement element)>();
}
```

It yields nothing.
But When I do

```
 this.ResultCollection[0] is (ElementRowViewModel parent, SpecificElement element)
```

It returns true, Or even

```
 this.ResultCollection[0] is (ElementRowViewModel parent, TElement element)
```

It also returns true.

Am I miss-understanding something? Or is there a limitation or a known bug with **Enumerable.OfType(IEnumerable)** when using tuple as type parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ValueTuple<ElementRowViewModel, SpecificElement>` value isn't a `ValueTuple<ElementRowViewModel, ElementBase>`. There's an implicit conversion from one to the other, but that's defined by the C# language (basically it performs element-wise conversion) not by the CLR type system, which is what `OfType` cares about.

```cs
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var strings = ("hello", "there");
        object boxed = strings;
        Console.WriteLine(boxed is ValueTuple<string, string>); // True
        Console.WriteLine(boxed is ValueTuple<object, object>); // False

        // This is still valid though: element-wise implicit conversions.
        (object, object) objects = strings;
    }
}
```

That second `is` test that returns false is effectively what the `OfType` method is doing, so it makes sense that your value isn't yielded.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look into source code for [`Enumerable.OfType`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Cast.cs,4ba4a3f8a5530e33) you will see that internally it calls [`OfTypeIterator`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Cast.cs,d25cf953c577dcd6) which looks like that:

```
private static IEnumerable<TResult> OfTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source)
{
    foreach (object? obj in source)
    {
        if (obj is TResult result)
        {
            yield return result;
        }
    }
}
```

To reproduce this behavior you don't need enumerables, just having a generic method with `is` check inside is sufficient:

```
static bool IS<T>(object o) => o is T;

(ElementRowViewModel Parent, ElementBase Element) y = (new ElementRowViewModel(), new SpecificElement());
var z = (object) y;
Console.WriteLine(y is (ElementRowViewModel, SpecificElement)); // True
Console.WriteLine(IS<(ElementRowViewModel, SpecificElement)>(z)); // False
Console.WriteLine(z is (ElementRowViewModel, SpecificElement)); // True
```

You can see the difference between second and third statement via [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WRiqQLIAUAlLfY/xwCiAGxgBbGADsALgCUIAdwBqASxgK2EACYxhpAAoBDWDIA0pEeKnSAQoYDOMC6IkyeAT1IBeUh0nrnKxl5ZTUNbV1uc38FUgBlAAcYMBUAMxUwS1dpbi4AbkIAN2NSAC9vXwhgACtk6Q8CohwATg5PFXtfLOsQ1XVNHWFzROS0jO63fNIAemnSABUoAFcYQgwWjgBJOIAeIRcexT7wweGklPTMg7cAPg5SrinZ0gAxQ2FHNY3yjq7ruSOYQGujOo0uE3qTzmixWhD4DAAvvDSMj1khSMAIBA9NsdvM7lVamBpKQIDwvDdSaRfvNGkiCHCiMwsIFsr0gRFhIQ6AR6SRyCyIXZPgQefS1sz4ucxlcgtIQEKHKtRYQEUA).

Generic method just performs "simple" type testing (with IL [`isinst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.isinst) instruction) which will return false (cause type of `z` is `ValueTuple<ElementRowViewModel, ElementBase>` which is not equal to `ValueTuple<ElementRowViewModel, SpecificElement>`).

The non-generic check (`z is (ElementRowViewModel, SpecificElement)`) is actually turned by compiler into something like this:

```
ITuple tuple = obj as ITuple;
Console.WriteLine(tuple != null && tuple.Length == 2 && tuple[0] is ElementRowViewModel && tuple[1] is SpecificElement);
```

Which performs type check per tuple element which results in `true`.